# CSS: how to make the font icon and text under it closer?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I am new to css. I want to realize a div , which includes a font icon with a number under it. The definition is:

```
<div class="col-xs-3" style="text-align: center;">
    <span class="fui-like"></span>
    <p style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: 200;">500</p>
</div>
```

class 'fui-like' is a simple definition to get the font icon:

```
.fui-like:before {
   content: "\e907";
}
```

The result is as below:
[font icon with text under it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06oFU.png)

As you can see, there is some distance between the font icon and the text under it. I want to know if there is any method to make them closer?

Comment: This is difficult to answer as the font itself could have spacing/margin built in to it - can you make a fiddle?

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions:

Maybe you can play with the [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) CSS property, either on the `<div>` or its children. Try setting it to the same value as the font-size of your element, then try lower or higher values. (Or **better**, use simply "1", without unit, which works as a multiplier for the font-size value; and then try higher or lower value, eg. "1.1" or ".9". This way if your font-size value changes later, the line-height remains proportional to what you intended.)

Or check if your `<p>` element doesn't have margin or padding added to it, and try removing it (in this case it would be `margin-top` or `padding-top`).

(Same goes for the `<span>`, although normally it's not used as a block element so it shouldn't have any vertical margin or padding. But depending on your CSS that may be the case.)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the font icon and text closer by adjusting the line-height property in css.

Answer (score 0):

Give your p tag `margin:0`.

like:

```
p{
  margin:0;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z984n3gf/)**